# Outlook contextual addin can't find PLUS sign with regex

Tags: outlook, office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins, office365-apps

My rule looks like this

```
<ExtensionPoint xsi:type="DetectedEntity">
  <Label resid="contextLabel" />
  <SourceLocation resid="testResId" />
  <Rule xsi:type="RuleCollection" Mode="And">
    <Rule xsi:type="RuleCollection" Mode="Or">
      <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Message" />
      <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Appointment" />
    </Rule>
    <Rule xsi:type="ItemHasRegularExpressionMatch" RegExName="Test" RegExValue="\+1" PropertyName="BodyAsPlaintext" Highlight="All"/>
  </Rule>
</ExtensionPoint>
```

as you can see the regex is looking for a `+1` to highlight (my real regex does more than that, but this example is enough to reproduce the issue)

It seems like the search works, since it returns the results, but i see errors in the dev console and highlight is not happening.
My guess is Outlook is using the actual matches to highlight and put them into a new regex (which in fact cannot start with a plus sign).
The exception is:

```
constants.ts:1 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /+1/: Nothing to repeat
    at new RegExp (<anonymous>)
    at constants.ts:1
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at markElements.ts:54
    at AAQkADAzYTZlYTYyLWQyMGMtNDFhOS05MTAzLTQyYjJhNjBhMTYwZgAQAINoPf%2BPCdhNj6AVUpiXz4w%3D:347
    at Object.next (AAQkADAzYTZlYTYyLWQyMGMtNDFhOS05MTAzLTQyYjJhNjBhMTYwZgAQAINoPf%2BPCdhNj6AVUpiXz4w%3D:347)
    at a (AAQkADAzYTZlYTYyLWQyMGMtNDFhOS05MTAzLTQyYjJhNjBhMTYwZgAQAINoPf%2BPCdhNj6AVUpiXz4w%3D:347)
```

I did not find any documentation on the office addin development sites if/how should i escape these. Any idea?

Comment: `plus1` is not valid regex! You need to escape `\+`, since `+` in regex is a special character.

Comment: @BladeMight this is not my code running to exception, but Outlook. please check my posted regex, it IS escaped.

Comment: Try double escape it.?

Comment: Since that is in double quotes maybe you need to escape the `"\"` itself first: `RegexValue="\\+1"`?

Comment: @BladeMight If I double escape it, there is no result either, since the slash is not present in the text at all.

Comment: then put `+` in `[]`

Comment: @BladeMight thanks for guessing, but as far as the regex returns something starting with plus, it stops working. I need to highlight something starting with a plus.
meanwhile i tried to work around with including 1 char before the plus to the highlighting (which i actually dont want to!), like this `.\+1` but it either didnt find the text or had the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO this seems to be a bug in the Outlook reading pane. It seems to be passing the content found by the regex in the manifest to the other regex that is responsible for highlighting the matches in the reading pane (using markjs) as the regex pattern. This is what I see in the `markElements.ts` file, and `keyword` is the actual string found in the email body:

[image: markElements.ts]

Comment: yes, i have made an issue to github: https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/1089